# Is the offset of a pair variable/structure ever the same?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

suppose I have this

```
typedef struct{
  int n;
  double* x;
}array;

array a;
double* a_;

array b;
double* b_;
```

Is `&a_-&a == &b_-&b`, and so on for every couple array/double*?

In the negative case, how is possible to ensure this?

Comment: I would like to declare an alias of double*x externally to the structure with the same name of the structure but followed by an underscore.

Comment: @userXXX then why don't you just **do it?**

Comment: The compiler is free to arrange variables at it sees fit, or even discard them entirely if they aren't needed.

Comment: If I declare array a;double* a_=a.x; does not seems to work. At least within a macro for the pair. However this does no solve the problem when a.x is allocated.

Comment: @user2124204: maybe you want `array a; double **a_ = &(a.x);` Then you can use `*a_` as an expression that refers to the same location that `a.x` refers to. C doesn't have aliases for objects (C++ does, they're called "refereneces"), so in C you use pointers instead.

Comment: Thank you 2124204, I meant exactly what you wrote. I'll try that!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot rely on the addresses of separate variables having any particular relationship. Also, you cannot validly subtract addresses to different variables.

Perhaps if you could clarify *why* you want this (what are you trying to do?) it would be possible to actually help.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to add padding bytes between your variables. In general, it will depend on the alignment of your datas.

Answer (score 1):

no, some compilers will places 'small' variables in a different location to large structs\arrays.

To keep the together declare a struct that combines the 2 elements...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's compiler dependant and that the order of local variables is not fixed in the specification.

You may try to create a structure that wraps these members with a `#pragma pack` to avoid any padding bytes eventually added by the compiler.